# Do I need to configure my Nginx server to send PHP mails?

Tags: php, email, nginx

I am trying to send an email through php. But the mail() function keeps returning FALSE even though I am sure everything is correct.

After browsing through stackoverflow for similar problems, one answer stood out by saying that it could also be because of the server.

NOTE: The mail server part of the nginx server isn't configured yet. I have no idea if PHP needs that specific module in order to work.

```
# $email and $randomPassword already defined.

$subject = "New Password";
$message = "Your new password is ".$randomPassword;
$headers = 'From: contact@mail.com' . "\r\n" .
           'Reply-To: contact@email.com';

$checkMail = mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);

  if ($checkMail) {
    echo "Mail send";
  } else {
    echo "Mail not send";
  }
```

Comment: well, you have to configure php first of all to make sure it attempts to send email messages in a way that may work on your system.

Comment: I've been programming with PHP for years and the one thing I've learned is that sending email "the right way" is really hard. Not only do you have to set things up on your server, but you have to deal with reputation, etc. My advice is to use a service like Mandrill (http://mandrill.com/) to send emails through an API.

Comment: @arkascha And how do I do that exactly?

Comment: @BakerStreet Thanks for the advice, I will look into it if I can't figure this out.

Comment: @BakerStreet Mandrill offers a nice service. I especially like the ability to check previously sent emails in their content. But it does not make things work like magic. I have seen bugs in Mandrill (confirmed by their support) and you still have to make sure to construct your emails "the right way" ;-)

Comment: @Berkan Sorry! Your php engine reads a configuration. Many details get set up, one is how it sends emails. Look through the `php.ini` file used by your system (there might be multiple ones for different usage of php, CLI, FastCGI, CGI, HTTP) and look for the email options. Then, try to follow what the settings mean. How does your php setup try to send emails? What server is used? What do the logs of that server say?